# How to provide MetaData access for Spring '20 programatically?

Tags: customsetting, custom-metadata, release

I am new to profiles and permission sets. I have identified a list of metadata that I would need to give access to for certain profiles.

Please see:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_permissions.htm&type=5

SO for example I have a profile called 'Sales Consultant' and I want that profile access to a metadata called 'CMX Settings.'

While I can do that on the GUI, I would like to get it done using code.

How would I get about doing that?

Comment: Can you provide an example of one thing you would grant access to? That might help get you an answer - at the moment, the question itself isn't clear.

Comment: I added the detail above.

Answer (score 1):

The table `SetupEntityAccess` is programmatically accessible by SOQL/DML and contains the assignments of a number of different metadata types to a Permission Set including Custom Settings and Custom Metadata. For Profiles, every Profile has a related `PermissionSet` ID and the same data model applies.

To add a Custom Setting or Custom Metadata to a Permission Set you need its ID. You can SOQL the `EntityDefinition` table and find the `DurableId` value where `QualifiedApiName` equals the API name of the CS or CM. Then you can insert a `SetupEntityAccess` record with `ParentId` equal to the `PermissionSet` ID, and `SetupEntityId` equal to the `DurableId` value which should start with `01I`.

If Metadata API counts as "programmatically" then you can also add these permissions using Metadata API. Custom Settings look like this in Permission Set or Profile metadata:

```
<customSettingAccesses>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>MP_Settings__c</name>
</customSettingAccesses>
```

Custom Metadata looks like this:

```
<customMetadataTypeAccesses>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>QueryMapping__mdt</name>
</customMetadataTypeAccesses>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish this is to create a permission set, let's call it `Access CMX Settings` which you've configured to enable access to your `CMX Settings` custom metadata.

With this permission set in the org, now you can programmatically assign this permission set to a user via apex like this:

```java
User u; // your user reference

List<String> permissionSets = new List<String>{'access_cmx_settings'};

List<PermissionSetAssignment> psas = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();

for (PermissionSet ps : [
        SELECT Id
             , Name
        FROM PermissionSet
        WHERE Name IN :permissionSets
]) {
    psas.add(
            new PermissionSetAssignment(
                    AssigneeId = u.Id,
                    PermissionSetId = ps.Id
            )
    );
}
insert psas;
```